# Can we dominate the series $\sum_{m\in \mathbb N^d} e^{-2t (2|m|+d)^{r}}\leq C(t) C'$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Let $r>0, t>0.$

Can we dominate  the series $$\sum_{m\in \mathbb N^d} e^{-2t (2|m|+d)^{r}}\leq C(t) C'$$ where $|m|:=\sum_{i=1}^{d} m_i, m_i \in \mathbb N,$  $C(t)$ is some constant depending on $t$ and $C'$ is constant independent of $t.$

> My  question:  Can we find $C(t)$? I'm interested in the behavior  of $C(t)$ as $t\to 0$ and $t\in \infty$.

Comment: Can you explain a little more where this comes from, why are you interested and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @quarague: Thanks.  In one dimension I  guess and the answer is:  $e^{-2td} \frac{1}{e^{4t}-1}$

Comment: @quarague: Also this comes when we try to dominate  $L^1-$norm of Fourier series  $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N^d} e^{-t(2|n| +d)^r} e^{in \theta}$

Answer (score 0):

The general method to show these kind of estimates is to decompose $\mathbb{N}^d$ into layers like an onion. Say $2^k \le |m| < 2^{k+1}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. You can then estimate that each term in the $k$-th layer is smaller than $e^{-2t(2\cdot 2^{k}+d)^r}$ and that there are less than $2^{d(k+1)}$ terms in the layer. This should then give you a series depending on $k$ which can be summed. This should give you estimates for what happends for $t \rightarrow 0 $ and $t \rightarrow \infty$. I hope you can fill out the details yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Please  would give me some more hint? Thanks..